# strange text when extract the body of email from Gmail using IMAP

Tags: qt, email, openssl, gmail-imap

iam using QT and Qsslsocket to get some emails body from Gmail using IMAP, I started using the IMAP command to log in, check how many emails I have, and fetch the data from the email I selected I use this commands sure after connected to IMAP using hostname and port.

```
tag login username password
```

after login and check the number of messages using tag select inbox I use this command to extract the body of the email.

```
tag fetch message_number (body[1])
```

the problem is i got very strange words like this

```
    * 5 FETCH (BODY[1] {1856}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)
```

but the email contains normal message have normal words the strange is when i test with another gmail, i take this email from first email and send it forward message to my second email, it give me the normal text in it! so please any help i can't understand what is the problem, also what i tried is using openssl which give me same result as QT strange words, and javaMail library and extract text from first email it worked? so is the problem from the imap command i used or what?
Thanks in advance.
this a screenshot of the email message 
[image]
**Update**
when i start some search i checked that this message is encoded to base64 and when i used online decoder it convert to the normal text but the question now is what command should i use so that i can fetch this message body text in normal text automaticly if there is such away.

Comment: maybe http://kuikie.com/snippet/55-24/cpp/qt/qstring/cpp-how-to-check-if-a-qstring-is-base64-encoded/

Comment: You need to fetch the Content-Transfer-Encoding, and then use a Quoted-Printable or Base64 decoder if needed.  If you don't want to do this yourself, use an IMAP Library, not basic sockets.

Comment: Thank you its clear now, but last question please, so all the messages can come encoded in many cases and i should check for it and decode it right? and if you have a good link that explains all the possible encodes that can come from an email IMAP.